# How to implement the relation between an identity and a service?

Tags: architecture, service, soa, acl, zend-auth

I'm using Zend Framework to build an application where i make use of SOA for the usual reasons, and i've come across a problem i'm not sure how to solve. The app has an authentication step and i want to get ACL in there as well, but the problem is i don't know how to get service aware of a user identity without making everything unmockable. Thing is i'd like ACL checks inside services.

How do you usually do? Pass the identity to a service instance? Make it accessible via some kind of registry? I like when things are automagic, but i can't come up with a good solution here

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come up against this first-hand, and I'm not a PHP developer so I'm not sure how helpful this will be.

I think passing the identify would be fine, but not sure how you'd best do that.

- If you could trust where the information was coming from (and that messages weren't tampered, then you could pass the identity as an identifier, which you could then look up.
- better woudl be something a bit more secure, like a hash (?).
- I guess if you can encrypt the messages (or the sensitive bits in them) then it'd be okay.

How would you propose checking the identity of the user "inside" a service?

Comment: I solved it by caching the identity in a service which the other services communicate with, and also made support to just pass it to services that make use of it. Felt weird at first, but now it feels like a good solution